# I am looking to integrate a gmail widget

Tags: web, widget, gmail

This is for a internal portal , and I am looking for a widget that allows user to login to their gmail account and view their account. I tried the Google gadget but it shows the following error
"this is a builtin module, so the UserPrefs and Content are ignored."
also since gadgets are gonna be discontinued I am uncomfortable using that as a long term solution.

Even widget from widgetbox, netvibes etc. don't seem to be working.

Is it because there has been some policy change by Google preventing these widgets from working ? or am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to use the Google widgets in a my site, but unfortunalitly it doesn't work.
It gives the Content are ignored.

No widgets haven't work for my code.

I think there is a policy change in it. But i didn't have any clew about it.

Comment: seems to be the case , since all widgets i come across face this problem, so wondering is it worth it to invest time in building on my own , or will it get blocked/banned or whatever..

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'login to their account' and what you want to do. You can use OAuth where a user grants your application permission to access their account.

Google have their own library written in a number of languages - some examples using Java, Python and PHP can be found here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_libraries

When you use OAuth you register with Google and they give you a ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret - this is what identifies you application to Google.

Once you do that provide a link to allow them to login - this will take them to a Google login, they login with their account - then they grant permission.

I've had problems using OAuth with GMail but successfully managed it with say their Contacts. For example this is the code I am using to retrieve all a users contacts

```
        public List<Person> GetContacts()
    {
        OAuthParameters parameters = null;
        GOAuthRequestFactory requestFactory = null;
        ContactsService service = null;
        ContactsQuery feedQuery = null;
        ContactsFeed feed = null;
        List<Person> contacts = null;



        try
        {
            if (ConsumerKey == String.Empty) throw new ValueIsEmptyOrNullException("ConsumerKey");
            if (ConsumerSecret == String.Empty) throw new ValueIsEmptyOrNullException("ConsumerSecret");
            if (OAuthCallback == String.Empty) throw new ValueIsEmptyOrNullException("OAuthCallback");
            if (SignatureMethod == String.Empty) throw new ValueIsEmptyOrNullException("SignatureMethod");
            if (ApplicationName == String.Empty) throw new ValueIsEmptyOrNullException("ApplicationName");
            if (Token == String.Empty) throw new ValueIsEmptyOrNullException("Token");
            if (Nonce == String.Empty) throw new ValueIsEmptyOrNullException("Nonce");
            if (Verifier == String.Empty) throw new ValueIsEmptyOrNullException("Verifier");

            if (Scope == String.Empty)
                Scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds";

            parameters = new OAuthParameters();
            parameters.ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey;
            parameters.ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret;
            parameters.Scope = Scope;
            parameters.Callback = OAuthCallback;
            parameters.SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod;
            parameters.Timestamp = Toolbox.GenerateTimeStamp();
            parameters.Token = Token;
            parameters.TokenSecret = TokenSecret;
            parameters.Nonce = Nonce;
            parameters.Verifier = Verifier;

            requestFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("c1", ApplicationName, parameters);
            service = new ContactsService(ApplicationName);
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
            feedQuery = new ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));

            feed = service.Query(feedQuery); 

            if (feed.Entries.Count > 0)
            {
                contacts = new List<Person>();

                foreach (ContactEntry contact in feed.Entries)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (contact.Name != null)
                        {
                            Person person = new Person();

                            int idStart = contact.Id.Uri.ToString().LastIndexOf('/');

                            if (idStart > 0)
                            {
                                person.PersonId = contact.Id.Uri.ToString().Substring(contact.Id.Uri.ToString().LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                            }
                            else 
                            {                                
                                person.PersonId = contact.Id.Uri.ToString();
                            }

                            person.GivenName = contact.Name.GivenName;
                            person.Surname = contact.Name.FamilyName;
                            person.Birthday = contact.Birthday;
                            person.Initials = contact.Initials;
                            person.Location = contact.Location;
                            person.MaidenName = contact.MaidenName;
                            person.Occupation = contact.Occupation;
                            person.Photograph = contact.PhotoUri.ToString();
                            person.Surname = contact.Name.FamilyName;

                            if (contact.Emails.Count > 0)
                                person.Email = contact.Emails[0].Address;

                            contacts.Add(person);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw ex;
        }

        return contacts;
    }
```